# csrf chack with phalcon php and angular

Tags: php, angularjs, phalcon

I am using Phalcon PHP with angular JS, and I have a form with toke hidden input:

```
<input type="hidden" name="{{ security.getTokenKey() }}" value="{{ security.getToken() }}" >
```

I submit the form with `ng-submit`. In the controller, I did:

```
$post   =   $this->request->getJsonRawBody();

foreach($post as $postName => $postValue) {
   $_POST[$postName]   =   $postValue;
}
if($post && $this->security->checkToken())  {

}
```

But the check token return false. Anyone have any idea??

thx

Comment: You getting false but the token is in the `$_POST`?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add a session adapter to your Dependency Injector?

```
$di->setShared('session', function() {
    $session = new Phalcon\Session\Adapter\Files();
    $session->start();
    return $session;
});
```